# programmatically assign a product collection to a category

Tags: magento-1.9, magento-1.8, magento-community

I would like to programmatically assign a product collection to a category.
This is my product collection for example

```
$_productCollection = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')
->getCollection()
->joinField('category_id', 'catalog/category_product', 'category_id', 'product_id = entity_id', null, 'left')
->addAttributeToSelect('*')
->addAttributeToFilter('category_id', array(
        array('finset' => '345'),
        array('finset' => '320')
        )
)
->addAttributeToSort('created_at', 'desc');
$_productCollection->getSelect()->group('e.entity_id');
```

I want these products to be assigned to a category id. Is it possible?

Comment: check this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6491548/programatically-add-magento-products-to-categories

Comment: the link you provided is for a single product. What about a product collection? Do I have to loop it?

Comment: if you know the categor_ id and product_ids you can use this Mage::getSingleton('catalog/category_api')
  ->assignProduct($category->getId(),$p‌​roduct->getId());

Answer (score 3):

I will add an answer with the help of the above link i posted.

```
$collection = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection();

foreach ($collection as $product_all) {

    $product_id  =  $product_all['entity_id'];//This will give you the product id

    $product    = Mage::getModel('catalog/product');
    $product ->load($product_id);
    $categories = $product->getCategoryIds();


    $categories[] = 152;//HERE YOU CAN ASSIGN WHATEVER CATEGORY ID YOU WANT TO UPDATE

    $product->setCategoryIds($categories);
    $product->save();
}
```

Comment: Any help   https://magento.stackexchange.com/q/298467/57334 thank @Mujahidh

Answer (score 0):

Best way to assign a category to product collection.
Reference from core code - app\code\core\Mage\Catalog\Model\Resource\Category.php

```
$write = Mage::getSingleton('core/resource')->getConnection('core_write');
$categoryProductTable = Mage::getSingleton('core/resource')->getTableName('catalog/category_product');
$productData = array();$position=0;
foreach ($_productCollection as $product) {
    $productData[] = array(
        'category_id' => (int)$catId,
        'product_id'  => (int)$product->getId(),
        'position'    => (int)$position
    );
}

$write->insertMultiple($categoryProductTable, $productData);
```