# Magento 1.9 - How to assign all products in a sub categories to it's parent categories?

Tags: category, magento1.9.2.3, bulk-actions

My products assigned as sub categories and child categories, how to assign all products in a category to it's parent categories.

eg:

Books/Children/Boys, Now the products assigned with Boys child category, how to assign parent category Books.

Answer (score 0):

This unfortunately is a super manual process. You can either manually add each product individually to the parent category or you can write a script that will traverse your entire catalog and do the work for you.

Most of the time in my experience you have the data entry people just select the category tree all the way up. There was a lot of first time pain with this, but once it was done for the current product set it was not difficult to maintain.

Comment: 25K products available in my website, any other possible way exits?

Comment: You're going to have to write a script that goes through your entire catalog and does the work for you.